# Declare MIME of document within it?

Tags: html, mime

Can I explicitly declare the MIME-Type `text/html` within a HTML document without using:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

?

Comment: did you try google?

Comment: of course i did but I couln'd find anything. I only found the two variants using the `http-equiv="text/html;utf-8"` and the `charset="utf-8"`. But the second variant should be preferred over the first one and using both at them at the same time is disallowed, [as defined here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-http-equiv-content-type). I'm just currious about that question whether this is even possible or not